# systools.make_tar can't find .app files in the .ez archive

Tags: erlang, release, erlang-shell, reltool

I am creating a release with `reltool`. The output folder `rel/lib` contains all the applications with their `ebin` folders packed into `.ez` archives, e.g. for `crypto`:

```
crypto-2.2
crypto-2.2/priv/ (with some files in the priv folder)
crypto-2.2.ez
crypto-2.2.ez/crypto-2.2/ebin/crypto.app
crypto-2.2.ez/crypto-2.2/ebin/ (with some .beam files in the ebin folder)
```

I start `erl` in the `rel` folder. The path to the `ebin` folder is in the code path, i.e. `code:get_path().` returns amongst other (and similarly for other apps in the `lib` folder):

```
"/usr/home/g/work/project/rel/lib/crypto-2.2.ez/crypto-2.2/ebin"
```

But yet when trying to call `systools:make_tar("releases/0.1/project").` it complains that it can't find the `.app` files (for all the apps mentioned in the release):

```
crypto: File not found: "crypto.app"
```

I see the `.app` file is in the archive, it's only that `systools` can't see it because of some reason. I tried to specify the `ebin` folder when calling `make_tar` using the `path` option but it doesn't seem to be working (the same error that `crypto.app` is missing). Also:

```
file:consult("/usr/home/g/work/project/rel/lib/crypto-2.2.ez/crypto-2.2/ebin/crypto.app").
```

gives me: `{error,enotdir}`.

Maybe `systools` doesn't handle archives yet? Is there any other way of creating the tar archive from a release made with `reltool`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid this altogether by also excluding the ebin directory from the .ez files by adding the following to your reltool.config

```
{excl_archive_filters, ["^include$","^priv$","^ebin$"]}
```

In most cases, this will basically mean disabling the creation of the majority of the .ez files, but the release should still work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I know that. But that would mean disabling .ez archives altogether (as currently only ebin goes there). So, instead of disabling the feature I would rather find a way of making it working, or hear from someone that indeed in some old modules accessing files inside .ez archives don't work. But in a way it is a workaround for the problem. Just not what I am (ideally) looking for. BTW another workaround would be unpacking all .ez archives and running systools then, but again, it still doesn't seem like the right solution.

Comment: Understood. I don't know a solution then. I don't remember the exact reasons I stopped using .ez files, but I ran into enough complications that I decided it wasn't work the hassle. If you haven't asked the Erlang mailing list, I'd recommend giving that a shot.